# Why is the defold rendercam crashing in self.data.lpos?

Tags: lua, camera, defold

I'm trying to use the rendercam, but it is giving me this error:

ERROR:SCRIPT: /rendercam/camera.script:147: vmath.vector4 only has fields x, y, z, w.

stack traceback:
     [C]: in function '__index'

I looked through the code and found self.data as a container with lpos = self.lpos. lpos is assigned to go.get_position(). The error is in the line self.data.lpos = go.get_position(). How is this causing an error and what can I do to fix it?

I've tried printing its position (which seems to be the problem) but the same error is thrown when it put   print("position is ", go.get_position()) in any place other than init.

ERROR:SCRIPT: /rendercam/camera.script:139: vmath.vector4 only has fields x, y, z, w.
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '__index'
    /rendercam/camera.script:139: in function /rendercam/camera.script:137

Comment: You'll need to post more of the stack trace and way more of your code if you want help.

Comment: I would recommend that you either create a ticket in the RenderCam repo (https://github.com/rgrams/rendercam/issues) or post this question on the Defold forum (forum.defold.com) and tag Ross Grams, the author of the repo. Asking here will not give much visibility to your question.

Comment: You can start with the fact that `self.data.lpos` appears to be `vmath.vector4` and `go.get_position()` returns `vmath.vector3`. You can try `self.data.lpos.x = go.get_position().x` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I accidentally assigned ob as a vmath.vector3 when trying to make ob.velocity a vmath.vector3.